# Create rolling dice in Reality Composer

Tags: ios, xcode11, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm trying to create a dice game in Reality Composer.

Created a cup and dice in Blender, exported them as .obj files and converted them to .usdz.

The cup has a rigid body (passive) and the dice a rigid body (active).

The goal is to put the dice into the cup, turn the cup so the dice roll out.

However, it seems the cup doesn't have a «hole» in it but the whole cup is just a box. Because when I hit play, the dice «jump» out of the cup. The collision-form in RC is set to «automatic» for the cup and capsule for the dice.

The dice don't «roll» either. They move across the surface, but keep their rotation (which is kinda not what a dice should do ;)

I activated physics in RC as well with the same settings (fixed, dynamic) as in blender.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[Edit] experimenting with different materials, I was able to make the dice «kinda» roll. Using Gummi and a much smaller gravity, I get the best results so far. I also came to the conclusion, that applying a force to the dice might be better than trying to put them into the cup (I can still do that but just not using the cup as a real object).

The last thing that doesn't work, though, is that the dice don't fall on their plane sides. Sometimes they just end up on their corners (which is not what a die should do, in my experience ;)

Comment: Not a full answer, so just a comment to point in the right direction. 1. A cup is a concave shape, but RealityKit doesn't simulate those. With some RealityKit code you can fake a concave shape as a compound of other shapes (e.g. a square cup is four walls and a floor), but you can't do that through the RealityComposer GUI so you'd need to look into integrating RC assets with RK code. 2. Using cubes for your dice should lead to more realistic behavior than capsules (assuming six-sided dice).

Comment: Thanks @rickster for that insight. I abandoned the idea of the cup. But my dice still won't roll as they should. I found out that when I use just cubes that are MUCH bigger than the actual dice should be, I get somewhat of a dice roll. Still far away from what I expect, though.